# Correct syntax for include CSS multi property in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have this:

> document.getElementById('returning_user_search_box').style.backgroundColor='yellow';

and now I need to add more style such this:

> margin-left:-280px; margin-top:-280px; min-width: 550px;

I tried some combination such this one but without success:

> document.getElementById('returning_user_search_box').style.innerHTML='{margin-left:-280px; margin-top:-280px; min-width: 550px;}';

Any clue ?

Comment: General rule of thumb is _CSS_ attribute `foo-bar` becomes _JavaScript_ property `fooBar`, and preceding hyphens are dropped (e.g. for `-webkit-*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set them all separately:

```
var style = document.getElementById('returning_user_search_box').style;

style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
style.marginLeft      = '-280px';
style.marginTop       = '-280px';
style.minWidth        = '550px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set them all separately. You could create CSS classes and just bind the classes in javascript. Another option would be to use jQuery which supports multi-property CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple styles on an element using the `cssText` property of the `style` object of the element.  You can also append to it to not clobber existing styles.

```
var style = document.getElementById('returning_user_search_box').style;

style.cssText += "margin-left: -280px; min-width: 550px;";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQnTX/1/

You could also loop over the object you have (which is syntactically incorrect by the way) and assign properties individually:

```
var properties = {"margin-left":"-280px", "margin-top":"-280px", "min-width": "550px"},
for (prop in properties) {
    if (properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        style[prop] = properties[prop];
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQnTX/

Answer (score 0):

General rule of thumb is *CSS* attribute `foo-bar` becomes *JavaScript* property `fooBar`, and preceding hyphens are dropped (e.g. for `-webkit-*`).

This means that you can make a simple transformation function for it

```
function toJSProp(cssAttrib) {
    return (
        cssAttrib
            .replace(/^-+/, '')
            .replace(/-([a-z])/g, function ($0, $1) {
                return $1.toUpperCase();
            })
    );
}
```

Next, make a function to loop over an *Object* and set *style* of a given element to it's properties

```
function style(element, cssObject) {
    var i;
    for (i in cssObject) element.style[toJSProp(i)] = cssObject[i];
}
```

Now you can many apply styles by passing an *Object* easily

```
style(document.body, {
    'color': 'red',
    'background-color': 'black'
});
```